# In Jquery carouFredSel paging need next & last links to hide after page number X

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

Am using Jquery carouFredSel in website, so need to show paging

> First Prev 2 3 Next  Last

Like I explained above, please let me know is this possible or not.

Here you can find the plugin

http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: What have you tried? Reading the documentation it should be pretty easy with 'currentPage()'. Simple call that function and check if you need to hide/show the prev/next buttons

Comment: am asking about paging next & last, not carousel next, i think am clear

Answer (score 0):

You have the documentation with this plugin : [**Custom Event**](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/custom-events.php)

In the custom Event tab, there are some events that you can use like :

> **prevPage**     >  Triggering this event will scroll the carousel one page backward.
>
> **nextPage**     >  Triggering this event will scroll the carousel one page forward.
>
> **slideToPage**  >  Triggering this event will scroll the carousel to the passed page.

It's possible to add button in the slider and call one of these events.